# Same class in different pages in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have a class of a game that became too big to fit on one page.

I want too have many pages that are all related to the same class, so I can put my code according to subjects in separate pages.

Same as I have many classes, I need to have many pages of the same class.

So, how can I do that in Xcode?

Comment: This information can not lead you the answer you want. You need to post some relevant code you have tried.

Comment: I'm not sure whether code is required here. It's a general question about Xcode functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Objective-C Code into multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357775/split-objective-c-code-into-multiple-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code is not divided into 'pages' like a Word document. Instead, you may write lines like this anywhere in your source files:

```
#pragma mark <A section name here>
```

For example:

```
@implementation SantaClass

#pragma mark gift delivery

- (void) descendChimney {
   ...
}

- (void) deliverPresents {
   ...
}

#pragma mark hospitality abuse
- (void) eatMincePies {
   ...
}

- (void) drinkSherry {
   ...
}

#pragma mark NaughtyOrNiceProtocol methods

- (BOOL) checkList {
   ...
}

- (BOOL) checkListTwice {
   ...
}

- (BOOL) childWasNaughty {
   ...
}

@end
```

To divide up your code into sections. You click on the section navigator in the top bar of the editor window in Xcode to jump between your sections. You can also use this to jump straight to a particular method. There is nothing stopping you using this technique to divide up your code into 'pages'.

Comment: I feel dirty for answering this.

Answer (score 2):

Though this has started as an Xcode-related question, there is a different issue to discuss here.

If you feel that your class is too big (which is a "code smell" in refactoring terms), you should refactor your class into smaller classes.

Generally speaking, you should divide the responsibilities of your current class, into smaller classes that have more well-defined functionality.

There are several refactorings that can help you do this. Take a look at [Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000OZ0N4Y) by Martin Fowler -it's the definitive book on the topic.

Comment: Our answers are complementary. :)

Comment: It's kind of working out that way today. I just realised it was you on the Dispatch Table question. 1K for both of us today I think.